# Document AI Warehouse UI : CODE 500: Internal error encountered

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai, document-management

i have problem when accessing Document AI Warehouse UI. suddenly when i go to the UI, there's a popup asking for project number. when i entered my existing project number who works previously, CODE 500: Internal error encountered.  what more confusing is, i already follow all guidelines including join group and allow list. i even succed upload batch document and using Document OCR processor to folder i created in doc ai warehouse. any help will be appreciated. Thanks

inserting same project number that works before, and i expected it works without inserting project number again. previously i already setup everything and just need to sign in and work like what i expected. but now i just got message CODE 500: Internal error encountered

Comment: Typically, a 500 error means that Google's backend code crashed. Try again in a few hours. Sometimes Google includes more details in the error message sent to the browser console. Use the inspect feature to see if more details are available.